# CSS:Defining Styles for input elements inside a div

Tags: css

I have a div called "divContainer" inside which i have few input elements like textboxes,radio buttons et..
How can i define the style for then in the CSS ? I wanna mention styles for elements inside this purticular div.not for the entire form.

Ex: For textboxes i need width as 150px;
    For Radio buttons i need width of 20px;

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can define style rules which only apply to specific elements inside your `div` with id `divContainer` like this:

```
#divContainer input { ... }
#divContainer input[type="radio"] { ... }
#divContainer input[type="text"] { ... }
/* etc */
```

Comment: Good point Mike; I've revised the code sample to use CSS3 selectors.  Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't using CSS3, you should include the javascript here to make this work: http://www.dustindiaz.com/input-element-css-woes-are-over/

Answer (score 12):

CSS 3

```
divContainer input[type="text"] {
    width:150px;
}
```

CSS2 
add a class "text" to the text inputs then in your css

```
.divContainer.text{
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: You can use the javascript linked above to eliminate adding classes.

Comment: true, but then you may get 'screen pop' as the javascript is evaluated and makes changes to the css.  For style changes involving dimensions, I personally like to avoid using js on them where possible.  But thats me :)

Comment: `.divContainer.text` should be `.divContainer input.text`

Answer (score 6):

Like this.

```
.divContainer input[type="text"] {
  width:150px;
}
.divContainer input[type="radio"] {
  width:20px;
}
```

Comment: This isn't necessarily backwards compatible with browsers that don't support CSS3

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html  works all the way back to IE 6, good enough for most people.

Answer (score 4):

When you say "called" I'm going to assume you mean an ID tag.

To make it cross-brower, I wouldn't suggest using the CSS3 `[]`, although it is an option. This being said, give each of your textboxes a class like "tb" and the radio button "rb".

Then:

```
#divContainer .tb { width: 150px }
#divContainer .rb { width: 20px }
```

This assumes you are using the same classes elsewhere, if not, this will suffice:

```
.tb { width: 150px }
.rb { width: 20px }
```

As @David mentioned, to access anything within the division itself:

```
#divContainer [element] { ... }
```

Where [element] is whatever HTML element you need.